# Changing screen position of UIView/UIControl upon tapping it

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm well aware this is a simple question. I would like to learn how to move a CGRect/UIButton to a different spot on the screen when the user selects it. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
- (void)showMeSomeButtons:(CGRect)frame{

    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(240, 150, 50, 50);

    UIImage *buttonGraphic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];

    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonGraphic forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self.viewController action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview:button];
}

-(void)buttonClicked{

    ???
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need to add a `:` in the `@selector(buttonClicked:)` statement since `IBAction`s expect a single `(id)sender` method attribute.

You can do something similar to the code below.

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
   CGRect frame = button.frame;
   frame.origin.x = 500; // new x coordinate
   frame.origin.y = 500; // new y coordinate
   button.frame = frame;
}
```

If you want to animate it, you can add the beginAnimation block.

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    CGRect frame = button.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 500; // new x coordinate
    frame.origin.y = 500; // new y coordinate

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.25];
    button.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Comment: Two questions on this, when I enter the top code it tells me that "CGRect has no member named 'x'" and the same for 'y' did I forget to add something. And also this is a more basic question but what is the (id)sender added for in the top line? Thanks so much.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, just updated my answer. It's actually frame.origin.x.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/eventoverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html) IBAction has the following requirements: "[…] the return type is void. The remaining required part of the signature is a single parameter typed as id and named (by convention) sender." So the colon is **not** optional. Edited your answer accordingly. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

`CGRectOffset(rect, dx, dy)`

Moves the origin of the rect by the delta X and Y.